# overflow: scroll on an element that go out of his parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

I got a little problem when i want to put an overflow: scroll on an element. That element is going outside his parent and i want to just make it scroll. 
I remade the problem on codepen so you can check it. 
I would like to keep the entire page to not scroll. Just the element i want would be able to be scrolled.
Sorry for my english.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.website {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.yes {
  height: 150px;
}

.container_scroll {
  overflow: scroll; /* not working*/
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/5f4bd7a6-f763-4518-9b81-bdfd40ce3fc9/d26yer1-421bb5b8-9fc2-4d5a-b2d1-1e1f81b26b82.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzVmNGJkN2E2LWY3NjMtNDUxOC05YjgxLWJkZmQ0MGNlM2ZjOVwvZDI2eWVyMS00MjFiYjViOC05ZmMyLTRkNWEtYjJkMS0xZTFmODFiMjZiODIucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.p5vfqGmq9kIylfG3glHGa20CAPUtoWlAxKEGpIvGOi8">
<div class="website">
  <section>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="my_text">
    <div class="container_scroll">
      <div class="yes"></div>
      <div class="yes"></div>
      <div class="yes"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to scroll on the y-axis (up and down, not left to right), it's not scrolling because you don't have a height set on the parent. You only have height set on the children for a total of 150px a piece, or 450px overall. Also - if you want to make sure you ONLY scroll up and down, you'll want to specify that you want to only scroll on that axis, and not the other - as seen below.

If you tried changing the overflow property to auto instead of scroll (a good way to check if it will have any overflow because scrollbars ONLY appear if needed) - you see that a scrollbar doesn't appear - so there is no overflow currently.

If you want to have a scroll, you'll need to set the height to less than the overall height of the children (450px).

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.website {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.yes {
  height: 150px;
}

.container_scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Add vertical scrollbar */
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/5f4bd7a6-f763-4518-9b81-bdfd40ce3fc9/d26yer1-421bb5b8-9fc2-4d5a-b2d1-1e1f81b26b82.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzVmNGJkN2E2LWY3NjMtNDUxOC05YjgxLWJkZmQ0MGNlM2ZjOVwvZDI2eWVyMS00MjFiYjViOC05ZmMyLTRkNWEtYjJkMS0xZTFmODFiMjZiODIucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.p5vfqGmq9kIylfG3glHGa20CAPUtoWlAxKEGpIvGOi8">
<div class="website">
  <section>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="my_text">
    <div class="container_scroll">
      <div class="yes"></div>
      <div class="yes"></div>
      <div class="yes"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i actually dont want to set a height in px. I would like that the parent takes all the space required without getting out of the screen. Like responsive. But a height: 100% doesnt work